# Moving randomly placed boxes with the mouse

Tags: javascript

I have created a program that populates the canvas with randomly positioned boxes with random colors. That part was easy, problem im having is that I would like to move any of these colored boxes around with my mouse. As well, the pointer must stay a costant distance from the top-left corner. My code is below, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
window.onload = init;


function init() {

var x= Math.floor(Math.random()*400);
var y= Math.floor(Math.random()*400);


var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");



//  Repeat to draw a rectangle 100 times
    for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
    var color = '#'+ Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
    context.fillStyle = color;

    //Each rectangle is at (0 ~ width of window, 0 ~ height of window)
    //Each rectangle's size is 50x50)    
        context.fillRect(Math.random()*window.innerWidth, 
    Math.random()*window.innerHeight, 50, 50);
  }

  document.body.appendChild(canvas);

  }

var mousePiece = null;

function init2() {
//we are grabbing the div elm by uts id
// var divEl = document.getElementById("ace");
var cx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
//divEl.style.top = getStyle(divEl,"top");
//divEl.style.left = getStyle(divEl,"left");

addEvent(cx, "mousedown", mouseGrab, false);
}

function mouseGrab(e) {
var evt = e || window.event;
mousePiece = evt.target || evt.srcElement;

addEvent(document, "mousemove", mouseMove, false);
addEvent(document, "mouseup", mouseDrop, false);
}

function mouseMove(e) {
var evt = e || window.event;
var mouseX = evt.clientX;
var mouseY = evt.clientY;

mousePiece.style.left = mouseX + "px";
mousePiece.style.top = mouseY + "px";
}

function mouseDrop(e) {
mousePiece = null;
removeEvent(document, "mousemove", mouseMove, false);
removeEvent(document, "mouseup", mouseDrop, false);
}

function addEvent(object, evName, fnName, cap) {
if (object.attachEvent)
    object.attachEvent("on" + evName, fnName);
else if (object.addEventListener)
    object.addEventListener(evName, fnName, cap);
}

function removeEvent(object, evName, fnName, cap) {
if (object.detachEvent)
    object.detachEvent("on" + evName, fnName);
else if (object.removeEventListener)
    object.removeEventListener(evName, fnName, cap);
}

function getStyle(object, styleName) {
if (window.getComputedStyle) {
    return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(object,  
null).getPropertyValue(styleName);
} else if (object.currentStyle) {
    return object.currentStyle[styleName]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The bad news is that the canvas element is a pixel map: when you draw something on it, you modify pixel values as if you were updating an image. Drawing on the canvas does not create HTML elements that can be assigned an id, grabbed, or moved around using `event.target` (the target in your case will be the canvas element).

The good news is that there are canvas libraries that create an object model on top of the canvas for items separately placed and then allow you to move them around. For example have a look at [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) for demonstrations of the operations it supports. Feel free to do more research on your options!

---

Also note two issues with the random color string:

1. Use Math.floor instead of Math.round to avoid ending up with a value of 2^24 (also corrected in ALFmachine's reply)
2. Defining CSS colors usig a hex digit string requires either 3 or 6 hex digits preceeded by '#'. To avoid color values being discarded by the CSS parser in your case, lead fill the hex digits with '0' to make up the 6 digits as required.

You could construct a CSS rbg() color string using three random integers in range 0 to 255 as the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider [JQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/) draggable. I made you a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kLznc8c9/5/) with random colors and all. There are many things you can do with JQuery UI so check the docs to find exactly what you need.

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
for ( var i = 0; i < 50; i++ ) {
    var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    var ranNum = Math.round( Math.random() * 65 )
    $( ".boxHolder" ).append( '<div class="pos' + i + ' draggable ui-widget-content"></div>' )
    $( ".pos" + i ).css({
        "background" : "#" + randomColor,
        "top"        : 10 * i + "px", 
        "left"       : ranNum * 6 + "px"
    })
}
})

$( function() {
   $( ".draggable" ).draggable()
})
```

Comment: Obviously if one has no need to explore the use of <canvas> elements one can create HTML elements and drag them. Is the question homework?

Comment: no, i just thought it would be cool if i could drag the boxes around.

Comment: this is way to drag them around but not in canvas. here's a good answer someone posted on dragging canvas images. Hope that helps. [Stack_Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566764/drag-objects-in-canvas)