# Drag event not firing with angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a canvas and I want users to be able to drag graphic elements around it. Thus, I don't want the canvas itself to drag, but I want to handle dragstart, drag, and drop events when the mouse does those things.

I'm using Angular 2, so I have:

```
<!-- editor.component.html -->
<div #rendererContainer
  draggable="true"
  (dragstart)="onDragStart($event)"
  (drag)="onDrag($event)" 
  (dragover)="onDrag($event)" 
  (drop)="onDragEnd($event)"
  (dragend)="onDragEnd($event)"> 
</div>
```

Then in editor.component.ts:

```
onDragStart(event) {
  console.log(`starting`);
  event.preventDefault();
}

onDrag(event) {
  console.log('dragging');
  event.preventDefault();
}

onDragEnd(event) {
  console.log('drag end');
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

When I try dragging something, I get `starting` printed in the console, but that's it.  How do I get the other drag events to fire? Do I have to roll my own dragging from mousedown/move/up events?

Stand-alone example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qqwkmq).  I want "dragging" the div around to fire dragstart/drag/drop events, but it only fires the starting one.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `event.preventDefault();` from all your functions?

Comment: It moves the div when the drag starts, which I don't want.

Comment: Not sure if this would help but you can check these out- http://rectangleworld.com/blog/archives/129, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566764/drag-objects-in-canvas

Comment: Where is the canvas? Can you include it in the markup? If you could reproduce the problem in a stackblitz, it would be even better.

Comment: By the way, there is a typo at the end of the `(drop)` line (probably only in the question, not in your actual markup).

Comment: Added a link to https://angular-6db92z.stackblitz.io, which has a simplified example (the canvas part isn't really important).

Comment: Are you sure that the stackblitz link is correct? I don't see the code in it. I asked where the canvas is because you say in the question "I don't want the canvas itself to drag". Looking at the markup, I don't see how that can be an issue since there is only a div. The relation between the div and the canvas is not clear to me: is one the parent of the other, are they siblings?

Comment: Sorry, hadn't used stackblitz before. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qqwkmq should be the right link. The canvas is a child of the div, but I only mentioned it to explain why I want this behavior, it's not an essential part of the question.

Comment: What you want is not clear to me. If you remove `event.preventDefault()` from `onDragStart`, then you can see the events. But you say that you don't want the div to move. So you want to drag the div but you don't want it to move?

Comment: Be careful with everything regarding drag events, as firefox and chrome have different implementations of it and support different events

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not have to use `event.preventDefault()`. This is only necessary if you want to use pure JS.

Try this Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x7umar

Also refer to the MDN implementation guide to choose the right events for your purposes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drag

### Further steps

If you want to modify the dragged element, simply implement some CSS adjustments inside your `dragstart` and `dragend` handler of the `event.target`:

```
onDragStart(event: DragEvent) {
  console.log(`starting`, event);
  // Hide dragged element
  event.target.style.opacity = 0;
}

onDragEnd(event: DragEvent) {
  console.log('drag end', event);
  // Show dragged element again
  event.target.style.opacity = 1;
}
```

With `event.target` you have the complete manipulable DOM element of the dragged element.

Answer (score 3):

try with

```
(dragover)="onDragOver($event)"
(dragleave)="onDragLeave($event)"
```

Component

```
onDragOver(event) {
    // do something
    event.preventDefault();
}
onDragLeave(event) {
    // do something
    event.preventDefault();
}
```